# Visual Studio 2012 Publish DLL as artifact for other project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

i have two Applications, using some DLL´s of each other.
1st App has 8 DLL Projects in the Solution and 1 Winforms Project
2nd App has 4 DLL Projects in the Solution and 1 Winforms Project

App1 usees 5 of the DLL´s Projects of App2, and App2 uses 2 DLL Priojects of App1.

ATM i copy the DLL from one App to an Lib Folder of the other App and reference to it. But i have to copy it again when i change things.

Is there a simple solution where i can put it on a FileShare without Team Solution?

And when TS is the only way, what are the best practices on it.

Regards
Lord_Pinhead

Comment: The standard way to share assemblies across solutions is NuGet. Why not package your assemblies into NuGet packages and publish them somewhere? Then you get versioning control built in too.

Comment: Not so clear why it has to be difficult, create a solution with all 14 projects.  And use project references.

Comment: NuGet is maybe a solution in the future, now it is to much work to setup an nuget server and move it all up there.

Comment: @HansPassant Rip appart the Projects would create to much trouble. The Libraries have their concerns (i.e. one is for OR, one for the logic, on ust objects, one for CustomControls, etc.), when i start rip them appart i think my solution would crash. Not to mention my Git Repo.

Comment: No projects need to be ripped, you modify the *solution*.

Comment: Oh, you mean i just add the to my Solution, ok that is one solution you can do if you are sure the path will never changes. But yes, you´re right, i could do that to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you have three possible solutions.

- **Side by side**

If you want to keep your app portable you could set up a side by side implementation. Create a core folder Put the shared DLL's in there and then reference them that path. Remember to turn off copy local.

### [image]

*Gotcha*

Bare in mind though that if a fresh pull of the source is pulled and the core folder cannot be found then there will be issues.

- **Nuget**

This solution would require more effort than the side by side implementation but is probably the best solution
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/06/28/creating-nuget-packages/

- **GAC**

The issue with this solution is your apps would no longer be portable.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, i will use the first solution for now, later i could create my own nuget Repo an use that instead.

Comment: No problem. Could you mark my press the tick next to the answer if you belive it to be correct. Thanks

Comment: Done :) (8 More to go)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a postbuild script to copy the dll to desired folders or others app folders:

take a look at [Msdn Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx)

Comment: Wasnt that bad of an idea, simple xcopy in the dll projects to the shared folder and reset my references.

Comment: Yeap. my intention is only to show you the possibilities... Some situations the dll werent not used in the code, isn't copied (always copy local true)... but if this used in other dll and not present causes some error...  Sometimes this script was a good solution...